# Web notification service pattern like Facebook or Twitter

Tags: rest, web-applications, web, notifications, design-patterns

I've never done a notification service on web client and I just would like to know what is the most common pattern.

Like if the server has to push the client or if it's the client which needs to get the server info every minutes for example.

Or if there is another pattern.

Comment: The HTTP protocol is stateless and the server has no knowledge of the client once the request has been fulfilled, so it is the responsibility of the client to seek updates from the server. I don't know much about the subject but you could look into a long polling or socket based solution (similar to Signalr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to implement push notifications:

HTTP Long Polling : The client initiates a request. The server checks if it has any new notifications. Irrespective of whether or not it has new notifications appropriate response is send and connection is closed. After time X client initiates another request (+ Very easy to implement - notifications are not real time. They depend on X since data retrieval is client initiated. As X decreases overhead on server increases )

HTTP Streaming: This is very similar to HTTP Long Polling however the connection is not closed. The server sends chunked response. So as soon as server receives new notification that it wants to push it can simply write to the socket. ( + lower latency than long polling and almost real time behaviour / overhead of closing connection and re opening reduced - memory usage client side keeps on piling up / ugly hacks etc )

WebSocket: TCP based protocol provides true two way communication. The server can push data to client any time. ( + ve: true real time - some older browsers dont support it ). Read more about it WebSocket.org | About WebSocket

Now based on the technology stack there are various solutions available:
(A) Nodejs : the cross-browser WebSocket for realtime apps. ( does heavy lifting for you. Gracefully falls back in case websocket is not supported )
(B) Django : As mentioned previously you can use signals for notifications. Also you can try django-websocket 0.3.0 for supporting websocket
(C) Jetty / Netty and Grizzly (Java based) : All have websocket support

from [link](http://www.quora.com/Web-Applications/How-are-push-notifications-technically-designed)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what web framework you use. With a modern framework like [meteor](/questions/tagged/meteor), it's very easy for the server to push notifications to clients, and many kinds of display updates can happen automatically, without having to construct a notification mechanism to take care of them.

Have a look at the two Meteor screencasts listed at http://meteor.com.